# iOS, use a variable that conforms to objc protocol in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

I have `MyObjcClass` with a member variable of type `UIView<FooProtocol>* myView`

`MySwiftClass` extends `MyObjcClass` and attempts to use the `myView`.

`myView.doFoo()` is an error in swift, because swift sees `myView` as `UIView` not `UIView<FooProtocol>`

Comment: declare the type of your myView ... var myView: protocol<FooProtocol>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a good direct mapping from `UIView<FooProtocol>*` to Swift.  Your best bet is probably just to cast it and then make the call:

```
(myView as! FooProtocol).doFoo()
```

If you have control over the objective-c class, it might be easier to redefine myView as FooProtocol:

```
id<FooProtocol> myView;
```

Or, define a method in the base class that invokes doFoo for you:

```
-(void)doFoo {
    [myView doFoo];
}
```

In which case, you can just use the base class method from swift:

```
self.doFoo()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    func foo()
}
class BaseFoo {

}
class Foo: BaseFoo, FooProtocol {
    func foo() {
        print("job as required by FooProtocol")
    }
}

class MyClass {
    var myFoo: Foo = Foo()
    var myFoo2: BaseFoo = Foo()
    // I dont have an idea about the type, but i know it comforms to FooProtocol
    var myFoo3: protocol<FooProtocol> = Foo()
}

let myClass: MyClass = MyClass()
myClass.myFoo.foo()     // job as required by FooProtocol
//myClass.myFoo2.foo()  // error: value of type 'BaseFoo' has no member 'foo'
myClass.myFoo3.foo()    // job as required by FooProtocol
```

Comment: In the original question, the base class originates in objective-c.  Showing an example with everything in Swift doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Your still missing the original question.  In objective C, the declaration "UIView<FooProtocol>* myView;" indicates that myView is any instance of UIView (or it's subclasses) that also implements FooProtocol.  It allows access to both FooProtocol and UIView methods.  Such a mechanism doesn't exist in Swift, so it just gets translated to `var myView : UIView`, losing the relationship with `FooProtocol` so `doFoo` is no longer directly accessible.  This isn't a question about how to do something purely in Swift, but in how to provide interoperability between ObjC and Swift.